# This project is set up to use Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. This mode can only be accessed from Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create firestore database but got the message "This project is set up to use Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. This mode can only be accessed from Google Cloud Platform".

This is setup using GCP. How can I do that? Also not able to switch to native mode. Please help me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812846/firestore-error-9-failed-precondition-the-cloud-firestore-api-is-not-availa/64812847#64812847

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This message indicates that your database was created in Datastore mode, when you created your project. You should be able to change it by accessing the Datastore Console using this link [here](http://console.cloud.google.com/datastore) and clicking in the available button to switch the mode - check [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDxNO.png). However, as clarified in this other post from the Community [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810154/how-do-i-completely-delete-cloud-datastore-from-a-project), you can only do it once and if you have not performed any changes in your database.

In case you don't fit in these above scenarios, you will need to create a new project and configure Firestore from the beginning.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks @gso_gabriel. Yes you are right, we can switch to Firestore mode only if not performed any changes in the database, but unfortunately I did that earlier. So nee dto restructure by creating new project. Thanks alot for your response.

Comment: I have not changed any configuration. suddenly how does it converts to Datastore mode ??

Comment: i was able to switch even after creating some entities in Datastore mode, simply delete all the data / entities, and then wait for some time. Open the firestore console again after some time and you should see (this)[https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDxNO.png] banner which allows you to switch

Answer (score 18):

1. Go over to Firestore Database
2. Click on the link provided
3. Change to Native Mode[image]

Answer (score 11):

you can switch mode anytime, the current db should be empty.

can do using cloud console easily

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases update --type=firestore-native
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue for days, and I was able to resolve it by installing the google-cloud-cli.

```
$ snap install google-cloud-cli
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud config set project "PROJECT_ID"
$ gcloud alpha firestore databases update --type=firestore-native
```

And the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sequence of steps. It is really useful and a better answer than all those 'one-liners' that fail because of the pre-requisite steps you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem on creating a fresh project.
I think it's default behavior with latest changes.
Just go to Datastore and switch to NATIVE MODE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer should be upvoted more. Somehow on creating a new project, it brings an error "Failed to provision Cloud Firestore.." then on refreshing page it say it's in Datastore mode. This is either a bug or bad UX

Comment: Error "Cannot enable Firestore for this project
An unknown error occurred" for Google Engineers

Answer (score 0):

I have better solution
that solution is ,
create new firebase project
initially when you create project ,don't do anything but create first firestore database
and ''' $ flutterfire configure ''' select new created project
100% it would work.
after that rest of the work you can do like authentication and storage rest of the things.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by simply go to google cloud CLI & then go to terminal & make sure you are in your project directory. Then fire the following command in terminal

```
gcloud alpha firestore databases update --type=firestore-native
```

Now go to firebase & refresh it , you will the FireStore Database is now enable