# Firestore : “Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Cloud Datastore projects”

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This error appears when initializing the Admin SDK in NodeJS.

> Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: The Cloud Firestore API is not available for Datastore Mode projects.

```js
 const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
 firebase.initializeApp({
     credentials: require('../gcp_credentials/firebase.json'), 
     databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com"
 });
 const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three solutions:

---

### 1. Firestore is not set as your Datastore

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/.
You'll notice a popup saying you need to initialize Firestore as the Native Datastore.
Once done you should see this

[image]

---

### 2. You are logged into the wrong account in GCloud SDK.

you're on `localhost` -
In your terminal you need to switch accounts or create a new configuration that points to the correct account and project.

Run `gcloud init` in a terminal on the machine you are using the service account on.

---

### 3. Firestore Database has not yet been created.

Open https://console.firebase.google.com/.
Add/Create your GCP Project, choose billing plan, and create the database.

[image]

If you get an error like this when trying to create the database...

[image]

You need to go visit https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/ first, click "Go to Datastore", go back to https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/ and retry the database creation.

You should now be able to interact with the UI

[image]

Comment: Nothing worked from the above. I've solved the error by creating at least one collection (my Firestore was empty).